# Count in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, grouping, report

How can I count the items inside a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it in the formula:
count({item_field},{group_field})

Answer (score 0):

> Right click -> Insert -> Summary

Then select the field to summarize and select "Sum" and press ok